# How to manipulate a tidygraph object from a list of tidygraph objects inR?

Tags: r, tidygraph

If I have a list of tidygraph objects, I want to remove list elements based on some condition. For example, if I have a list of tidy graph object, like so:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                    to = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3))
nodes_1 <- data.frame(name = c(NA))
edges_1 <- c()

tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes_1, edges = edges_1)

myList <- list(tg, tg_1)
```

Looking at the output of `myList` we can see that one of the tidygraph objects has no edges associated with it and the `names` column is `NA`.

```
> myList
[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 × 1 (active)
  name  
  <chr> 
1 Hadley
2 David 
3 Romain
4 Julia 
#
# Edge Data: 9 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
# … with 6 more rows

[[2]]
# A tbl_graph: 1 nodes and 0 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 1 × 1 (active)
  name 
  <lgl>
1 NA   
#
# Edge Data: 0 × 2
# … with 2 variables: from <int>, to <int>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to iterate through the list and check if any of the tidygraph objects have no edge data or are `NA` (like in the above example) and remove this object from the list.

I know I could manually delete the list using `myList <- myList[-2]`. But I was looking for a more general solution for when I have a large amount of tidygraph objects in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the list using `igraph::gsize()` which returns the edge count:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)

Filter(function(x) gsize(x) > 0, myList)  # Filter(gsize, myList) also works but potentially less safe.

# Or

purrr::discard(myList, ~ gsize(.x) == 0)

[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 x 1 (active)
  name  
  <chr> 
1 Hadley
2 David 
3 Romain
4 Julia 
#
# Edge Data: 9 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
# ... with 6 more rows
```

Comment: Both answers work great. I chose yours as the top answer as it requires less package dependancies. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
keep(myList, ~ .x %>% 
              as_tibble %>%
              pull(name) %>%
              is.na %>% 
              `!` %>% 
               any)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 x 1 (active)
  name  
  <chr> 
1 Hadley
2 David 
3 Romain
4 Julia 
#
# Edge Data: 9 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
# … with 6 more rows
```